# Always visible control in windows application

Tags: asp.net

I have a small issue with my windows application. I have a tabpage in tabcontrol. And I will be loading content in that tabpage by fetching data from database. In this, when I show huge text, I need to keep paging for this.

This page numbers, next page and previous page lables should be on top of the tabpage. Here unfortunately, I need scrolling for this tab page and when i scroll the page numbers will go because those page number will be on the top of the tab page.

Now I would require help in keeping this page numbers visible always even after scrolling this tab page. And i need this page numbers on the top of the tab page.

Comment: Ok now ? What to do? what you want?what you have tried?

Comment: It is not Ok now. When I scroll the page numbers are going. I need to keep those page numbers in the same position.

Comment: Ok can you move your screen little bit i can not see it from here 
how can we see it if you not post any code here what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

Once I scroll, I want the page number should be there only. For which I am unable to do anything. I just created a dynamic lable in runtime in C#. There is no great code to share.

I have uploaded some pics here but I am not sure why I am not able to see those here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6z9y.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaQhR.png